# WPF сохранение изображения из буфера в bmp

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Собственно код который был на WinForm, нужно сделать что-то подобное на WPF.

Ошибка  CS0104  'Image" является неоднозначной ссылкой между "System.Windows.Controls.Image" и "System.Drawing.Image".

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
    var bmp = (Image)Clipboard.GetImage();
    bmp.Save("123.bmp");
}
```

Прописывание ссылок не дало результат.

Comment: Контрол это контрол. А дравинг - другая либа, другая структура. Как преобразовать... смотреть свойства. Можно полистать MSDN

Comment: попробуйте вот этот ответ с международного SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749843/wpf-image-source-clipboard-getimage-is-not-displayed

Comment: *Ошибка CS0104 'Image" является неоднозначной ссылкой между* — ну, вроде понятно же написано. *Прописывание ссылок не дало результат.* — покажите что вы там написали. `var bmp = (System.Drawing.Image)Clipboard.GetImage();` — вот так должно работать.